# Find command: multiple conditions

Tags: find, filenames

As a standard for my file/dir naming I use something like putting date and tags string into the file name separated by underscore, eg:

```
2015_03_10_usa_nyc_vacations_album_pictures
```

For a long time I have used software's like Recoll, but usually it gives much more records than I need. Since my naming is pretty consistent I think there should be a way to scriptsize it using find command.

Although I know how to perform find searches for single conditions I am not sure how to  find multiple criteria/conditions. That is, how do I find all the files whose names satisfy certain conditions. Let consider the following examples that contain

1. {2015} AND {  {album} OR {picture}  }
2. {album} AND {vacations} AND NOT {2015}

Comment: Did you see the `-a` (and) and `-o` (or) operators to `find` in the documentation? Of course you can combine them with any other `find` operator like `-name` or `-newer`.

Answer (score 10):

for the first one

```
 find DIR \( -name 2015\* -a \( -name \*album\* -o -name \*picture\* \) \) -delete
```

where

- you have to escape `*` to avoid expansion
- you have to escape ( and ) to avoid subshell
- replace `-delete` by whatever you like

the second one is left as homework (hint `\!` )

Comment: I would not suggest `-delete`, but hey this is the more comprehensive answer. Maybe use `-print` or `-exec ls -al {} +`

Comment: @Archemar
As I cannot edit the post, please replace 'avoir' by 'avoid'.

Answer (score 7):

It's usually **not worth it** to type something like:

`find /dir -regex '.*2015.*\(album.*\|picture.*\)'`

Don't waste your time, use grep and the UNIX concept of "one tool for each task":

`find /dir | egrep '2015.*(album|picture)'`

Advantages:

- type less, get results faster
- more readable (no \, unnecessary .*)
- may run faster–piped commands allow the kernel to balance between two CPUs, yes I tested right now in my ordinary console)
- acts similarly in case you want to read from a list of files or other sources

Answer (score 5):

For the first one `find` with `-regex` would be good:

```
find /dir -regex '.*2015.*\(album.*\|picture.*\)'
```

For the second one that:

```
find . -name "*album*" -a -name "*vacations*" -a -not -name "*2015*"
```

Comment: Just in case someone didn´t know the meaning, -a stands for AND (likewise, -o stands for OR). Source: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html